# Session vs cookies on detecting user is login or not

Tags: php, cookies

How to use cookies in the register and login phase?

User logged in -> I use their id to set as cookies -> they closed the browser -> then when they come back, the main page detect whether there is a cookies -> if yes, log in the user back..

It doesn't sound right, because I need to store the username and password as cookies as well?

Comment: NEVER store usernames and passwords in cookies!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for `session` instead of `cookies`.

Here's a simple illustration.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
echo "Hi this is your first time. Enjoy the stay";
$_SESSION['user']='set';
}
else
{
echo "Thanks for coming back";
}
```

Comment: @IgorPantović Unless the user clears his cookies, it will work.

Comment: @Igor That entirely depends on how the session cookie is configured.

Comment: Terrible mistake on my part. I stand corrected, you two seem to be absolutely right.

Comment: @AndréDaniel if user clear the cookies, what will happen? your code about is about session, which i know cannot clear via browser?

Comment: @KaitlynSacco Sessions still use cookies, so if the user clears his cookies, his session will be lost and he would need to log in again.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are stored on client's machine and can be manipulated easily. Therefore, use session.
For "remember me" functionality, you should store token in a cookie and invalidate it each time user gets logged in using it. Also, make sure you set sensible expiration time.

There are **lots** of resources about this on internet. Have in mind, that **even this** way isn't absolutely bulletproof and many websites will require you to retype your password to do extremely important actions (such as changing login credentials, credit card number etc). You should **NEVER** trust user who got authenticated using a cookie completely.

Eg. you can let him see stuff as if he was logged in normally, but don't let him change his password/email without reconfirming the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Cookie is unsecure, one of the main reason is the expiration date is computed on your system date.

Use this code to authenticate your users after having verified their credentials

```
$_SESSION['created'] = time();
$_SESSION['last_activity'] = time();
```

Make a call of the following code for each page in your website. This will automatically expire the session after $session_expire seconds and protect you from [SESSION FIXATION attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation)

```
$session_expire = 3600;

// Check if user is online
if(isset($_SESSION['created']) && $_SESSION['created']) {
    // If the last request has been done before 'session_expire' seconds ago, we've to destroy this SESSION
    if (isset($_SESSION['last_activity']) && (time() - $_SESSION['last_activity'] > $session_expire)) {
        // logout the user          
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
    } else {
        // Update the last activity timestamp
        $_SESSION['last_activity'] = time();

        // Prevention from session fixation attacks
        if (time() - $_SESSION['created'] > $session_expire) {

            // Regenerating session_id
            session_regenerate_id(true);

            // Updating creation time
            $_SESSION['created'] = time();
        }
    }
}
```